# Pulling related data in MVC 3 from separate database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, multiple-databases, database-first

Being new to MVC and the Entity Framework I've had quite a few problems performing complex data queries.  I'm using a Database First approach I need to understand the best way to pull related data from a separate database.  I have connected to the databases and created the edmx files as well as the models from the existing databases.  I will simplify the problem example:  If I have one table with employee information:

```
Employee_Information(EmployeeID, FullName, Address, Phone)
```

Then I have a second (in another database)

```
Employee_Achievements(EmployeeID, Achievement, DateAchieved)
```

How can I tie these two together to pull the employee's information (name, address, etc.) in a view?  My initial thought was do a join and then pass that to the view:

```
var employee = from emp in db.EmployeeAchievements
join empInfo in emp_db.EmployeeInformation
emp.EmployeeID == empInfo.EmployeeID
```

The problem I have with this is that I'm already using a ViewModel with multiple models being passed to the view.  I need the ability to tie the information in for several employees at a time with something like this in the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < model.EmployeeAchievements.Count; i++)
{
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeAchievements[i].EmployeeID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeAchievements[i].EmployeeID)
            </div>
        </td>
// Display employee name next
```

Possible use of the ViewBag?  Or is there a way that I can associate the foreign key across databases?  Keep in mind this is  Database First so the edmx and model files are generated.  I haven't been able to find any good examples of what I'm trying to do here.  I would appreciate any help and can provide more detail if needed.

Comment: Why you just don't add 'List<Employy_Info> Infoes' and 'List<Employee_Achievement> Achieves' in your ViewModel? Then, in a View u can use it: Model.Infoes and Model.Achieves

Comment: What I don't understand about that approach is how to relate the data in the view.  How would I show "Employee Name" for the correct employee so that when I say model=>employeeAchievements[i] it pulls the correct name for model=>employeeInfo[i]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a class, that have got all the fields you need: id, name, achievement (or list of them if you have got one-to-many), date and so on - everything you need. So, for example, this class is named `EmployeeAchievement`. Then, you just modify your current ViewModel to have field of a type `List<EmployeeAchievement>` named `EmplAch`. Then, you have to build your view model:

```
YourViewModel model = new ViewModel();
model.EmplAch = (from emp in db.EmployeeAchievements
                 join empInfo in emp_db.EmployeeInformation
                 emp.EmployeeID == empInfo.EmployeeID
                 select new EmployeeAchievement 
                 {
                     EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,
                     AchievementId = emp.id,
                     Date = emp.DateAchieved,
                     Achievement = emp.Achievement
                 });
```

So, in your view you can use:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < model.EmplAch.Count; i++)
{
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmplAch[i].EmployeeID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmplAch[i].EmployeeID)
            </div>
        </td>
// Display employee name next
}
```

Comment: This makes sense now that I see it.  MVC has been a small pain to me coming from WebForms.  Thank you for your help.